# DataGridView doesn't update Enum in BindingList

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, enums, .net-4.5

The DataSource of my `DataGridView` is a `BindingList<Filter>` which contains an enum. The gridview contains only two columns: a regular textbox column for a string, and a combobox (drop down) column for the enum. If I bind the combobox column to the enum variable of my object I get an error. Here is the code for my objects:

```
public class FilterProfile
{
   public FilterProfile()
   {
      filters = new BindingList<Filter>();  // the list that gets bound to gridview
   }
   public string name { get; set; }
   public BindingList<Filter> filters { get; set; }
}

public class Filter
{
  public string keyword { get; set; }
  public FilterType type { get; set; }  // the enum in question
}

public enum FilterType : int
{
  SESSION = 1,
  ORDER = 2,
  SHIPMENT = 3
}
```

I have a form where the user selects a `FilterProfile` from a dropdown menu and then I find the appropriate FilterProfile from a global list and bind it:

```
foreach (PlvFilterProfile filterProfile in _filterProfiles)
     {  
        // find the correct filter profile
        if (filterProfile.name.Equals(lstFilterProfiles.Text))
        {
           // bind it
           grdFilters.DataSource = filterProfile.filters;
           break;
        }
     }
```

In order for the changes made in the DataGridView to be reflected in `filterProfile.filters` I need to set the `DataPropertyName` attribute of both columns to their respective variable (either `keyword` or `type`). This works correctly for the `keyword` string, but not with the `type` enum.

If I keep the line `colFilterType.DataPropertyName = "type";` I get the error below whenever a new row is created or whenever I put my mouse over the dropdown. If I get rid of it, the `type` of every newly created Filter is set to `0` and never updated.

[image]

I'm not sure what causes the DataError event so don't know how to handle it or where to breakpoint.

Comment: invoke dataerror event in datagridview in c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you focus on the new row (prepare to add a new row), a new object is required in the underlying list, this object is default by `null`, that value is bound to the new row and of course the `ComboBoxCell` can't accept that null value, causing the exception as you encountered. The solution is very simple indeed, we just need to handle the event `AddingNew` of the `BindingList`, set the default new object in there to a valid value and then it works just fine:

```
public FilterProfile()
{
  filters = new BindingList<Filter>();  // the list that gets bound to gridview
  filters.AddingNew += (s,e) => {
    //the default value of FilterType is up to you.
    e.NewObject = new Filter {type = FilterType.SESSION };
  };
}
```

Comment: Awesome! How can I upvote this answer twice? Great explanation of the problem and solution. Sometimes C# needs a little bit of magic  code to work.